# `DeclareCiteCommand`: how to print book titles, but not article titles?

Tags: biblatex, declarecitecommand

I'm writing a citation style for a beamer presentation. I'm trying to keep the citations in the footnotes and keep only the necessary information. Hence, I'm omitting the titles from journal articles, but now I'd like to cite books as well and I can't find how to include it in this style. My current code is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\printnames{labelname} \printfield{year}\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
        \printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal} \printfield{volume}, \printfield{pages}\printfield{eid}}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield[eprint:arxiv]{eprint}.
    }
    {\addsemicolon\space}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question its not totally clear, were you want the book-title to be printed. But you can use the `\iffieldequalstr{<field>}{<string>}{<true>}{<false>}` test (Biblatex doc p. 251) to test for the `entrytype` and print the title in case its `book` (which means `true` in boolean syntax):

```latex
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\printnames{labelname} \printfield{year}\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
        \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{book}{\printfield{title}}{\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal} \printfield{volume}},
        \printfield{pages}\printfield{eid}}%
    \newunit%
    \printfield[eprint:arxiv]{eprint}.
}
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Of course you could place the test at another position.

Hope that helps!